# Add autoloading results

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes it is a very annoying to click "next page" button and see when new page will be loaded. I think it will be very convenient to provide autoloading search result in Stack Overflow.

For example

1. User get first 50 results. And he see only 10, to see other he needs to scroll down
2. When user scrolls to the 40th result javaScript loads new page with 50 results.
3. When user scrolls to the 90th result javaScript loads new page with 50 results.

And so one. Also there is can be a protection to load, for example, only 50 result per 2 seconds (or meor) to prevent server to load many result in short period of time if user press and holds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> long time.

Comment: Can you write why you downvoting?

Comment: Please read the [what is meta?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) and specifically the 'voting is different on meta' section.

Comment: One needs to weigh the [pros and cons](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/03/infinite-scrolling-lets-get-to-the-bottom-of-this/) of implementing infinite scrolling.  Besides, as a personal aesthetic, I rather *like* seeing footers.  It contains useful information like what build number someone broke some useful feature.

Comment: I dislike infinite scrolling almost as much as I dislike parallax scrolling.

Comment: Oh god, parallax scrolling.  You just brought back some bad PTSD, @ivarni...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agree.

Infinite scrolling isn't pleasant at all.
No reference,
no evidence,
How much it remains?
Where am I?